# Magento 2: base URL to use in hardcoded links

Tags: magento-2.1.7, base-url

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop and  I have
created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

In the back-end, I have created a **block** with a custom, hardcoded, navigation like:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

The question: Is there a piece of code for the website's *base URL* (a term often used in Codeigniter), so that the code above can be reusable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `{{store url=""}}` for get base url of site in static block and pages.

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="{{store url=""}}">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{store url="about"}}">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{store url="blog"}}">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{store url="contact"}}">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can I use apostrophes: `<li><a href="{{store url='about'}}">About</a></li>` for better looking code?